# Redux action having another action as payload

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

Is it okay that redux action A has action B as its payload?

My use case is that I'm trying to store every ongoing API request and have my api state in following format:

```
type ApiState = {
    requests: { [id: string]: AnyAction }
    hasNetwork: boolean
}
```

Key of `requests` property is basically action `type` that initiated request (e.g. `USER_FETCH_REQUEST`) and value is action (whole action with type, payload, meta). I'm using `redux-observable` to filter every action with `type` ending with `_REQUEST` (project convention) and then, if its a match, dispatching a new action that receives initial api request action as parameter (payload) and updates `ApiState` with it.

Simple example:

```
const getUser = (id: string) => ({
    type: "USER_FETCH_REQUEST",
    payload: { id }
})

const addRequest = (action: AnyAction) => ({
    type: "API_REQUEST_ADD",
    payload: action
})

// somewhere in epic pipeline ("action" is result of getUser(id))
addRequest(action)

// resulting state
{
    "requests": {
        "USER_FETCH_REQUEST": {
            type: "USER_FETCH_REQUEST",
            payload: { id }
        }
    }
}
```

That way if my application goes offline and I have 5 requests in `ApiState`, I'd just dispatch all those actions once I retain network back (since action should have all required data to finish request correctly).

I'm also clearing those requests upon `_SUCCESS` or `_CANCEL` and have some custom logic on `_ERROR` but I'm just curious if above specification is anti-pattern and can lead to undesired application state?

Comment: You'll need to be careful about maintaining backwards compatibility with any stored actions that could be dispatched at who knows what time in the future but otherwise keeping a log of actions or calls to replay is certainly a common way to handle offline mode with redux.

Answer (score 0):

Logging or storing a list of actions is not an anti-pattern at all. Time Travel, a very popular use-case of redux, is achieved through exactly this.

However I think your code above seems a little over-engineered. A much simpler way of achieving the same result would be to just modify your actions to something like this

```
const getUser = (id: string) => {
  const action = {
    type: "USER_FETCH_REQUEST",
    payload: { id }
  }

  add_to_request_cache(action);
  return action;
}
```

Or, to make this easier still, write an action creator like

```
const actionCreator = (action: AnyAction) => {
  // Code that handles various types of actions like _REQUEST or _SUCCESS actions
  // add_to_request_cache(action);
  return action;
}
```

and then compose all your actions by wrapping them with this.